# How long could someone survive in free fall?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, drag, speed, biology

If there was hypothetically a bottomless pit (no ground), then approximately how far down could you possibly survive without being killed by the speed? (there is no vacuum so air resistance matters.)

Comment: Skydivers exist, and safely reach terminal velocity, so you could survive indefinitely, or at least until you die of thirst.

Comment: If the hole is on Earth, eventually the hole will become too hot and the person will die.

Comment: If there is a bottomless pit with air and gravity then air pressure would keep growing and eventually kills a human in a couple of dozens km of fall past 1bar level.

Comment: Devil's advocate here: If air resistance matters it is by definition not a free fall.

Comment: Why should the speed kill you (if you don't crash into anything)? Air resistance at terminal velocity supports your weight, so it is no different from floating face down in a pool of water.

Comment: If you can bring some consumables along, [you can stretch it out to a long, *long* time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_spaceflight_records#Most_time_in_space).  Admittedly, I put my hole *around* the planet, but that is—as they say—an implementation detail.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a human surviving a hypothetical situation which isn't really a physics question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not the speed that kills you, it is dehydration.

A falling person eventually reaches [terminal velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity) where the air resistance equals gravity ($V=\sqrt{2mg/\rho A C_d}$, where $m$ is the person's mass, $g$ is gravity, $\rho$ is air density, $A$ the area of the person and $C_d$ the drag coefficient). For humans this is about 54 m/s. This is certainly inconvenient and drafty but not deadly in any way, as skydivers experience it.

So assuming the bottomless pit is not also heated by geothermal energy (otherwise the falling person would be broiled; the crust is 200-400 C at the mantle boundary 30-50 km down; at terminal velocity this will be reached in 9-15 minutes), the person will just keep falling. Eventually they die of dehydration after a few days to a week. This is exacerbated by the constant wind, which is going to be removing moisture efficiently if the air is not rather humid.

There is another problem if we assume air pressure grows with depth (the bottomless hole presumably will have air flowing into it, which incidentally may speed the descent). You get nitrogen narcosis at around four times atmospheric pressure. Since pressure goes as $P=P_0 \exp(-z/H)$ where $z$ is your altitude and $H=RT/mg\approx 8000$ m is the [scale height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_height), this happens at $z=-H\ln(4)\approx -11~\rm km$. So you will likely pass out before too long, and then oxygen toxicity will get you.